# html form tag is sometimes absent in forms

Tags: html

Sometimes I see a form that is wrapped in a form tag

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

And sometimes there is no form tag, but just a div

```
<div class="view">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <button class="destroy"></button>
</div>
<input class="edit" value="<%= title %>">
```

How come sometimes the form tag is present and other times its not for forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to submitting information via [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/), HTML forms were the standard in sending information to a server from a web page.  They include the destination and method in the form attributes.  More recently, this can be handled without assigning these attributes in form and sent via Javascript; typically using AJAX.  This means the form element isn't necessary but is a good idea to include where possible to be syntactically correct HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Forms input types are not always used to send values, they could be use as controllers, like date difference purposes, ranges or sliders to control alpha chanel, or rotate and image, making calculators, showing or hiding stuff on the page, lots of purposes other than just submitting to other pages

Check this [code for a calculator](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bn89oodm/) on one of posts couple hours ago, lots of buttons, but not submitting anything

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" ID="button-cos" VALUE="cos">
```

Another example using `button` and `input type="text"` [online image editor tutorial](http://tutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tutspremium/flash-rias/067_easelJSPictureEditing/demo/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `<form>` tag is not used specially when developers decide not to submit data in a conventional manner. The `<form>` tag has the main purpose of wrapping all the inputs that will be submitted to the next page specified on the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag, and these data is sent using either POST or GET method indicated with the `method` attribute.

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method="post">
```

When the inputs are not wrapped by a `<form>`tag it means that the data is never submitted to another page or it submitted in a different way through javascript.

JavaScript is able to read the values of all the inputs and submit this data to a next page simulating a form or simply send it to the server without changing the page, when the page never changes but the data is sent to the server is when we say it was submitted using AJAX.